# Ajax Request Rejected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a file using an (jquery) AJAX request but it fails and the response sent is

`Request Rejected`

`The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
Your support ID is: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and provide steps to replicate the issue`

I've tried to visit the URL using browser and that works fine.

Is there anything related with the AJAX request or is it entirely a server side issue? How can I solve this?

Comment: What (if any) library are you using for AJAX Upload?

Comment: The fact you can "visit the URL with a browser" means it will accept GET requests.  but for a file upload you'll almost certainly be using PUT or POST and it looks like the server is not accepting those methods on that URL.

Comment: Don't just put -1, try to add a line or two to make sense of that -1

Answer (score 1):

Your message is being generated by a [Big IP ASM](https://f5.com/products/modules/application-security-manager)

When an Illegal HTTP status violation occurs, the BIG-IP ASM sends an HTTP blocking response page that includes the [OWS Server header](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/11000/000/sol11029.html).

So the problem is not on your side, it's on the web server side.

Answer (score 0):

When origin in request header is null, server doesn't allow request. read about CORS at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing  Cross Domain request can be allowed from php server as

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

and enable all methods for request.

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```